# QGIS export DEM to SAGA grid - no coordinate system

Tags: qgis, dem, export, saga, grids-graticules

I have created a DEM using survey points from a GNSS system. Works like a charm so far. I can extract elevation lines etc. However, when I export it as a SAGA grid it looses the coordinate system. I am able to open it in SAGA and run every module and terrain analyzing tool, but the grid is missing the coordinate system.

What am I doing wrong? When exporting to grid I choose the coordinate system that I want it to be in.

QGIS 3.8.0 Zanzibar
SAGA GIS 7.4.0

Answer (score 1):

When you export a DEM as a `SAGA Binary Grid`, QGIS produces three files:

- `DEM.sgrd` : a header file
- `DEM.sdat` : the main binary data
- `DEM.prj`  : CRS information

I guess you have lost `.prj` somewhere. Keep these three files in the same directory (folder) of your file system.